# Pagination Backend with findOne mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, pagination, backend

I'm trying to structure a findOne request to retrieve just the most recent 10 notifications on a specific user's account. Then if the user selects page 2, i would like to retrieve the 11th-20th most recent notifications and so on.

The problem I am facing is that using Notification.findOne and limit I do not have access to the total notifications length, so as the data is in the reverse order than i would like (the oldest is index 0), it's hard to structure the request to get the last 10 notifications, whilst not knowing how many are in there.

Is there a different approach to take, ideally I would be able to return from mongo db the notifications.length and depending on the number I pass through, either the first 10 notifications, second 10 notifications, third 10 notifications etc...

```
        const { page = 1, limit = 10 }: any = req.query;
        const dbResponse = await Notification.findOne(
            { userId: res.locals.user._id}, 
            {"notifications" : 
                {"$slice" : -limit}
            }
        );
        if (!dbResponse) {
            return res.status(HTTPCodes.NOT_FOUND).send({ message: "Notifications not found" });
        }
        const response = {
            notificationsPerPage: limit,
            notifications: dbResponse.notifications.reverse(),
            currentPage: page,
            totalNotifications: dbResponse.notifications.totalLength
        };
        return res.status(HTTPCodes.OK).send(response);
```

```
const Notification: Schema = new Schema(
    {
        userId: String,
        notifications: {
            type: Array,
            default: [],
        },
    },
);
```

Tried: reversing the nested notifications array and return the total notifications length (before slicing) without success

Comment: `Notification.findOne({userId}, {_id: 0, notifications: {$slice: [0, 10]}})`;

Comment: Hi, this would return the first 10 notifications, which are the oldest. I need to fetch the last 10 which is possible with $slice: -10, however then i would like to fetch the last 11th to 20th which is what I am struggling with.

Thanks for your suggestion! any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

it will do as you expected :)

> https://mongoplayground.net/p/-lXSwCZ6br7

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      userId: 1
    }
  },   
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$notifications",
      includeArrayIndex: "index"
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      index: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $skip: 2
  },
  {
    $limit: 2
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "userId",
      notificaations: {
        $push: "$notifications"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a super useful answer. Now I just have one problem, to retrieve the last 10 notifications I would implement $slice [-11, 10] and the 10 before that i would implement $slice [-21, 10] and so on.

My problem comes when we reach the end on the array, is there a way to retrieve just the remaining less than 10 notifications? For example, if there are 15 notifications, and on the 2nd pagination the req will be $slice[-21,10], atm the return will be the first 10 elements of the array, when I would like the first 5.

Comment: now i understood the prblm do the arraysort first in aggregation and then do the slice

Comment: Is that less memory consuming that finding the array length in a separate call first? and then using that array length in the next call to make sure that the start value is not greater than the number of notifications? Thanks for your help?

Comment: yeah it will consume more memory but it will work as you expected. :)

Comment: Hi @wolf_of_java_script, this is might be too late, i think this lib can help you to solve the problem [mongo-pagination](https://github.com/mrbontor/mongo-pagination). but the library is using MongoDb Native driver.